# Storybook not rendering component-level styles on Vue(scss)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, sass, storybook

I am trying to implement Vuejs(scss) with Storybook.
The components render fine but the component level scss i've written is not being rendered.

Must be some webpack issue. I've tried by best but nothing works.

My `main.js`

```
config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      sideEffects: true,
      use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    },{
      test: /\.pug$/,
      loader: 'pug-plain-loader'
    }
    );
    
    config.resolve.alias = {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "src"),
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.js'
    }
    return config;
```

My demo story

```
export default {
  title: 'Support',
  component: Support,
  argTypes: {
    variant: { control: { type: 'select', options: ['block', 'inline'] } },
  },
};

export const SupportStory = (args, { argTypes }) => ({
  components: { Support },
  template: '<support  :variant="variant"/>',
  props: Object.keys(argTypes),
});
```

A little scss code in my vue file

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "@/assets/styles/mixins/_breakpoints.scss";

.supportcard {
  @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
    background: $mist;
    color: $white;
  }
```